# Docker image for a customised version of JBoss Wildfly 16.0.0.Final

Tags: java, docker, jboss, wildfly, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have created a version of JBoss WidFly 16.0.0.Final with modules for Hibernate's OGM for MongoDB using a provisioning (provision.gradle) file.

```
provision {
    project.logger.lifecycle('>>>>> provision.gradle .....')

    // Optional destination directory:
    destinationDir = file("wildfly-as/16.0.0.Final")

    configuration = file('wildfly-server-provisioning.xml')

    // Define variables which need replacing in the provisioning configuration!
    variables['wildfly.version'] = '16.0.0.Final'

    variables['hibernate-orm.version'] = '5.3.7.Final'
    variables['hibernate-search.version'] = '5.11.0.Final'
    variables['hibernate-ogm.version'] = '5.4.1.Final'
}

<server-provisioning xmlns="urn:wildfly:server-provisioning:1.1" copy-module-artifacts="true">
    <feature-packs>
        <feature-pack
                groupId="org.wildfly"
                artifactId="wildfly-feature-pack"
                version="${wildfly.version}"/>
        <feature-pack
                groupId="org.hibernate"
                artifactId="hibernate-orm-jbossmodules"
                version="${hibernate-orm.version}"/>
        <feature-pack
                groupId="org.hibernate"
                artifactId="hibernate-search-jbossmodules-orm"
                version="${hibernate-search.version}"/>
        <feature-pack
                groupId="org.hibernate.ogm"
                artifactId="hibernate-ogm-featurepack-mongodb"
                version="${hibernate-ogm.version}"/>
    </feature-packs>
</server-provisioning>
```

I now want to create a Docker file to deploy WildFly 16 on AWS Elastic Beanstalk with my EAR.

As I understand things a valid Docker file must have FROM as its first statement. So I use:

FROM jboss/wildfly

Which is the base JBoss WildFly 16.0.0.Final image.

How do I know the directory structure for this image, as a (Home) Brew install(ed) version of WildFly is a slightly different structure from my (working) 'provisioned' one?

How can I create the Docker image from my own provisioned version of WildFly 16, which has all the OGM modules I need. Is it simply an 'ADD' to add my modules to it?

Comment: Well take a look at https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/wildfly/dockerfile it shows that wildfly is unarchived in /opt/jboss/wildfly You will need to provision it from there. Be careful to use the same user.  Another solution would be to get your configuration file an gradle then run the gradle task to construct your image

Comment: Had seen that page. It was the location of the modules directories which appear to differ. An issue also appears to be the Docker ADD command won't work across directories. Have moved the Docker file into my IntelliJ Project and I can ADD the ear and start WildFly The logs show the missing JPA/OGM modules. which I can now add.  Thanks got me thinking & kickstarted everything.

Comment: Fixed "unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /Users/NOTiFY/IdeaProjects/GoStopHandle/Dockerfile: no such file or directory" by moving to the projects root directory and running with the '-f' option for the Docker file: 'sudo docker build -f ./wildfly-admin//Dockerfile --tag=wildfly-admin .'